# How to work with Session in Rails_API gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Currently I am working i my project, and that project 
using
rails_api gem. I want to add session management for authentication, but 
it
seems the session does not working. Here is my configuration in
config/initializer/session_store.rb:

```
Pmcapi::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {

key: '_pmcapi_session',
expire_after: 1.hour

}
```

and in my session_controller, I adding session to store token

(in session_controller.rb)

```
def create
  #just to generate new token
  user.reset_sso_token!
  session[:token] ||= user.sso_token
  self.current_user = user
  redirect_to root_path
end

when i am in application_controller, i want to access session[:token] 
but
the result is nil (in application_controller.rb)

def authenticate_user!
  #puts("User Authentication")
  #puts(request.authorization)
  #puts(request)
  @user = User.authenticate_with_token(session[:token])
  #head :unauthorized unless @user.present?
  redirect_to sign_in_path if @user.nil?
end
```

Please, i need help. I have stucked with this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `config.api_only = false` in your config file as stated in [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#other-middlewares)?

> Session Management: If a config.session_store is supplied and
>   config.api_only = false, this middleware makes the session available
>   as the session method in ActionController.